# How do I know whether a URL returns an HTTP 404 status code?

Tags: url, 404, http

For any given URL, how can I (dis)confirm whether it returns an HTTP 404 status code?

I found [this tool](http://404checker.com/) but isn't there a cleaner, more natural way to find out, independently of other people's tools?

For example, how do I know whether this [broken link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02221706&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) is a genuine 404 or not? I took a quick look at the source code but I saw nothing about a 404 status code.

**Edit**

I found what I was looking for in developer tools/Google Chrome Console. The broken links turns out to be a 404 indeed:[image]

Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) are sent on the HTTP level (e.g., when requesting resources), so you can’t find them in the HTML. The server decides which status to send when you request a page, so the very same page could send *404* and ten seconds later *200*.

Various tools can be used to display the received HTTP status codes.

You could use

- your browser, which most likely ships with developer tools (like Firefox: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> )
- command line tools (like [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL): `curl -I http://en.wikipedia.org/`)
- web apps (like the one you mentioned)
- … (If you are looking for a specific tool that matches your requirements, you could create a question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/))

Note that it’s possible (i.e., if the server is configured in such a way) that different clients (based on user-agent, language settings, IP address etc.) get different results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have firebug you can see the difference, they actually return the 404 header.
A website is perfectly capable of returning content with a 404-header:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo file_get_contents('page-not-found.html');
```

So: How to check for the statuscode:
[See answer 1 for a cURL solution, answer 2 for a get_headers() solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php), or use your console's resources tab to check for them manually

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you could check with cURL if you're interested in building your own 404 checker. An [example with PHP](http://thisinterestsme.com/check-see-http-resource-exists-php/):

```
$resourceUrl = 'http://example.com/test.html';

$ch = curl_init($resourceUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($statusCode == '404'){
    //resource does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebug with Page Speed (generally helpful for web developers) then you can look in the Resources tab.

[image: Firebug with Page Speed]

This will show you the HTTP header returned for every resource on a page, including the page itself. This also helps identify redirects on the way to a 404 page if things on your site aren't coded/configured properly.